# How can I make <th> in bootstrap with half column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make table columns like this with <th> in bootstrap?

```
0.5 | 1.5 | 2.5 | 2.5 | 2.5 | 2.5
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You are talking about the width of the column, no ?

Comment: just because the content length

Comment: Yes, the width of table columns

Answer (score 0):

Bootstraps columns are fixed in size...

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

If I'm on the right lines you could use a `col-md-12` which would span the whole `container` and then you would have a define the widths of your own table...

Of course, you could change the BS columns but this would be very bad practice and could cause further issues down the line.